# Servlet.service() for servlet Dispatcher threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jboss6.x

The output on browser is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException   
com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFDispatcher.service(TSFDispatcher.java:152)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

The output on console is

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SNet].[Dispatcher]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet Dispatcher threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFDispatcher.service(TSFDispatcher.java:152) [tsf-base.2.5.FCS.jar:]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1] 
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_16]
```

Comment: at com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFDispatcher.service(TSFDispatcher.java:152) [tsf-base.2.5.FCS.jar:], This class has thrown NullPointer at line 152, check that class

Comment: its in a jar file and part of framework. Is it some configuration issue.

Comment: most likely, check the configuration file for the library, you might be missing something

Comment: Should i put my configuration files here.

Comment: is it a compatibiltiy issue, I mean tsf-base.2.5.FCS.jar is not compatible with servlet api jar 3.0?